# Run event when GameObject scale changes in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to trigger an event when the scale of a GameObject changes. I didn't find anything about this online. Maybe someone can help me out here.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like this built in. You should move what causes the change of scale  in a  dedicated code / script that somehow also raises the event you want.

Comment: another alternative would be to have a script to "poll" the object scale  (i.e. just read the property) at regular interval, keep previous value and compare with new one.

Comment: Or don’t write code that changes the scale make it use a method so you can tell.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really something built-in.

You can either poll check like e.g.

```
private Vector3 _currentLocalScale;
public delegate void ScaledChangedDelegate(Vector3 from, Vector3 to);
public event ScaledChangedDelegate ScaleChanged;

private void Update()
{
    var newLocalScale = transform.localScale;

    // Depending on you required precision
    // Vector3 == has a precision of 0.00001
    if(_currentLocalScale != newLocalScale)
    // If for some reason you need it more exact
    //if(Vector3.Distance(_currentLocalScale, newLocalScale) <= Mathf.Epsilon)
    {
        ScaledChangedDelegate?.Invoke(_currentLocalScale, newLocalScale );

        _currentLocalScale = newLocalScale ;
    }
}
```

---

The alternatives - for the freeks ;)

- use the [`TransformSetterInterceptor`](https://github.com/handzlikchris/Unity.TransformSetterInterceptor) which is quite hack and overwrites the way how `Transform` is compiled and injects callback events for all the property setters.
- use [`MissingUnityEvents`](https://github.com/handzlikchris/Unity.MissingUnityEvents) which more or less does the same but even more flexible by basically adding some generic callbacks for the property changes. It can simply be imported as a [Package](https://github.com/handzlikchris/Unity.MissingUnityEvents#usage) and allows you to generate such weaved-in callbacks for any type and property you like.